# How to maintain self-made libraries?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, qt-creator, include-path

I'm using Qt Creator 2.7.0 on ubuntu 13.04.

I've just recently ran into the idea of using libraries, and they're a whole new thing for me.
I've just figured that I need to have the following in my application's `.pro` file to use a library of my own:

```
LIBS += -L<lib's dir> -l<lib's name>
INCLUDEPATH += <headers' dir>

// for example:
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyLib/release/ -lMyLib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MyLib/src/
```

As you see, I have all my projects in a folder called `Programming` (the `..` in this case)
Each of my project have `.pro` and `.pro.user` files in the root, source files in a sub folder `/src` and the release in an other sub folder `/release`.

So, this is what my `Programming` folder looks like:

```
Programming
   MyLib
      MyLib.pro
      MyLib.pro.user
      src
         myclass.h
         myclass.cpp
      release
         libMyLib.a
         Makefile
         myclass.o
   MyApp
      MyApp.pro
      MyApp.pro.user
      src
         main.cpp
      release
         main.o
         Makefile
         MyApp
```

However, I figured that I could create a folder `Programming/libs/`, and add `libMyLib.a` and `myclass.h` files inside that `libs` folder.
I would do the same for all of my libraries, and then I could always include them like this:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib/ -lMyLib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib/
```

The problem is, I'd get include path for every library stored on my computer and the `libs` folder would become a mess, especially if there are two headers with same name on different libraries.

I'm really new to using libraries, is there a general solution on how they should be located on your computer, and how to include them into your projects?

Answer (score 2):

You could mimic libraries like Boost and have a directory tree like this:

```
MyLib
    build
        Makefile, .pro or .sln file here
    lib
        MyLib
           // your .so / .a here
    include
        MyLib
           // your .h here
    src
           // your .cpp here
    CMake or qmake file here
```

This way you have an out-of-source build tree (in `build/`) so that your binary files are not mixed up with your source files.

The `lib/` and `include/` directories are handy because you can then define an `install` build target. If you then type

```
 make install
```

it will copy everything to `usr/local/lib` and `user/local/include` so that your App can simply do `#include <MyLib/some_header.h>` and you can link directly against your library binaries (because you copied everything to a location in your system wide path). There is also no danger of name clashes because you wrapped it inside your own MyLib subdirectory.